# Does a TTL get triggered from the time the record is created or at a certain interval like a cron job?

Tags: dns, ttl

I just wanted to get a basic understanding of how TTLs work from the stand point of when exactly the record will refresh. Say I create a DNS record with a TTL of 1800 at 09:05 UTC, does that mean it will refresh at 09:35 UTC or 09:30 UTC?

This behaviour is important for me to understand as if it is the latter (where the record gets refreshed at 1800 second intervals - so every half an hour), then I can time my DNS record updates so that they are within a couple of minutes of refresh time so as to limit the amount of time the request points to the old address.

Any assistance on this is much appreciated.

Comment: As published of a zone you can not time anything. The DNS is not top down, you are not pushing changes to recursive nameservers, recursive nameservers are requesting you for records when they do not have it or when their previous ones expired (outrun their TTL). Which also means that each recursive nameserver will have records at some moment with different TTLs, depending on when they asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://www.varonis.com/blog/dns-ttl/
>
> DNS TTL (time to live) represents the time each step takes for DNS to
> cache a record. The TTL is like a stopwatch for how long to keep a DNS
> record.

In other words, a DNS record with a TTL of 1800 (30 minutes) will "live" for 30 minutes ... *from the time it is received by the caching server*.

From the same link:

> How Long Will it Take My DNS to Update? To honestly know that everyone
> is seeing an updated DNS record, it is essential to calculate how long
> it will “actually” take to propagate across DNS. This is accomplished
> by using the following formula
>
> `TTL X (number of steps) = Fully propagated`
>
> For example, if your set TTL is 1800 seconds and there are five steps
> (not counting the authoritative server), then your fully propagated
> time would be 9000 seconds or no longer than 2 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: I do not know where the second paragraph comes from and what it means, but it is certainly not like that that the DNS works. What are the "steps"? This makes no sense at all...

Comment: Well I guess my main question was answered in the sense that the DNS records are refreshed (by a caching server) a set amount of time after it was first cached and not on a periodic basis (which would have been great).

Comment: I also didn't understand the "steps" calculation. Granted there may a number of intermediary caching servers between a client and the authoritative server, say it takes 1 second for the record to be cached at each step, wouldn't the full propogation time be 1800 + (1*n) -> where n is the number of intermediary steps?

Comment: @PrathameshDatar Again, there is NO propagation. DNS is not top down and continuing to think it is that way will never make you understand how it works. If recursive nameservers are cached, the final one will get a TTL at most equal to the first one, or less, so they are not added between themselves at each "step", whatever that is, the linked resource makes no sense and is certainly not how the DNS works.